# What is the problem in my code ? [ SESSION ]

Tags: 8, sessions

I create a code for my form . When I choose a product in node,data send to my form page and sessions sav data and then I chose seconde product I see two products in my form page . But when I refresh page just show 1 pruduct . What is the problem ?

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $session_manager = \Drupal::service('session_manager');
    $session_manager->start();
    $newlabel = \Drupal::request()->request->get('label');
    $newcode = \Drupal::request()->request->get('code');
    $newprice = \Drupal::request()->request->get('price');
    $newsellercode = \Drupal::request()->request->get('sellercode');

    if ((isset($_SESSION['loop'])) and ( isset($newcode)) and ( !in_array($newcode, $_SESSION['code']))) {
        $_SESSION['loop'] = $_SESSION['loop'] + 1;
        $_SESSION['label'][$_SESSION['loop']] = $newlabel;
        $_SESSION['code'][$_SESSION['loop']] = $newcode;
        $_SESSION['price'][$_SESSION['loop']] = $newprice;
        $_SESSION['sellercode'][$_SESSION['loop']] = $newsellercode;

        for ($count = 0; $count <= $_SESSION['loop']; $count++) {
            $forms[$count] = [
                '#markup' => '<tr><td>' . ($count + 1 ) . '</td><td>' . $_SESSION['label'][$count] . '</td><td>' . $_SESSION['code'][$count] . '</td><td>' . $_SESSION['price'][$count] . '</td><td>' . $_SESSION['sellercode'][$count] . '</td></tr>',
            ];
        }
    } elseif ((isset($_SESSION['loop'])) and ( isset($newcode)) and ( in_array($newcode, $_SESSION['code']))) {
        for ($count = 0; $count <= $_SESSION['loop']; $count++) {
            $forms[$count] = [
                '#markup' => '<tr><td>' . ($count + 1 ) . '</td><td>' . $_SESSION['label'][$count] . '</td><td>' . $_SESSION['code'][$count] . '</td><td>' . $_SESSION['price'][$count] . '</td><td>' . $_SESSION['sellercode'][$count] . '</td></tr>',
            ];
        }
    } elseif ((isset($_SESSION['loop'])) and ( !isset($newcode))) {
        for ($count = 0; $count <= $_SESSION['loop']; $count++) {
            $forms[$count] = [
                '#markup' => '<tr><td>' . ($count + 1 ) . '</td><td>' . $_SESSION['label'][$count] . '</td><td>' . $_SESSION['code'][$count] . '</td><td>' . $_SESSION['price'][$count] . '</td><td>' . $_SESSION['sellercode'][$count] . '</td></tr>',
            ];
        }
    } elseif ((!isset($_SESSION['loop'])) and ( isset($newcode))) {
        $_SESSION['loop'] = 0;
        $_SESSION['label'][$_SESSION['loop']] = $newlabel;
        $_SESSION['code'][$_SESSION['loop']] = $newcode;
        $_SESSION['price'][$_SESSION['loop']] = $newprice;
        $_SESSION['sellercode'][$_SESSION['loop']] = $newsellercode;
        for ($count = 0; $count <= $_SESSION['loop']; $count++) {
            $forms[$count] = [
                '#markup' => '<tr><td>' . ($count + 1 ) . '</td><td>' . $_SESSION['label'][$count] . '</td><td>' . $_SESSION['code'][$count] . '</td><td>' . $_SESSION['price'][$count] . '</td><td>' . $_SESSION['sellercode'][$count] . '</td></tr>',
            ];
        }
    } else {
        $forms = [
            '#markup' => 'Nothing',
        ];
    }


    $form['loop'] = [
        '#markup' => '<span style="color:#454545">' . $_SESSION['loop'] . '</span>'
    ];
    $form['theme'] = [
        '#theme' => 'basket',
        '#content' => $forms,
    ];
    return $form;
}
```

Comment: Don't start the session in the session manager. If you put data in $_SESSION drupal will do this automatically.

Comment: Thanks but without start the session I have problem too.

Comment: Don't start the session yourself, this will not solve the problem. Your code should work without, but it seems a bit complicated and is not easy to debug. Usually you store form data in $form_state until submit. Often you can rebuild the form only with the user input, because if a field has user input you know that it exists.